# How do I delete all normal maps from all materials?

Tags: python, scripting, normal-map

I am seeking a way to delete ALL normal maps from ALL materials.
Is anybody able to post a script that can do this?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: u want a python script that goes through all materials and deletes the normal map node?

Answer (score 2):

##### Delete all normal map node in all materials

```
import bpy

mats = bpy.data.materials

def del_normal_map(mat):
    try:
        tree = mat.node_tree
        nodes = tree.nodes

        for node in nodes:
            if node.type == 'NORMAL_MAP':
                nodes.remove(node)
    except:
        print(f"fail : {mat}")

for mat in mats:
    del_normal_map(mat)
```

Comment: Line 7 seems to be getting an error when I run the script, are you able to fix it up?

Comment: What is the error message on your console?

Comment: It works now that you've edited it, thank you!